# Cannot open /private/etc/hosts file form terminal

Tags: terminal.app, hosts-file, mamp

#### Problem with /private/etc/hosts file

I was trying some software (MAMP PRO) and it has problems writing to the /private/etc/hosts file (the software has admin rights).
I thought it was the software but then realized that if i type in Terminal:
`sudo open -t /private/etc/hosts` it gives me `file does not exist` which for starter it's not true and using the same instruction in Terminal i can open any other file of the `etc` folder.
So obviously i have trouble with that file and must probably that's the reason MAMP PRO can't write it.

Comment: Can you open it in the terminal without resolving default text editor with `open` command? Such as: `sudo less /private/etc/hosts`?

Comment: `sudo less /private/etc/hosts` gives me `/private/etc/hosts: No such file or directory`.                `sudo open /private/etc/hosts` gives me `The file /private/etc/hosts does not exist.`

Comment: How about the standard path of `/etc/hosts`? Also, which version of macOS are you on?

Comment: Right -- you've got something wrong about the filepath. Make sure each directory exists where it says its should: `sudo ls /private`, `sudo ls /private/etc`, `sudo find /private/etc/host*`, etc. As @mjb2kmn said, the hosts file usually lives at `/etc/hosts`, not `/private/etc/hosts`

Comment: thank for your comments guys. It was my mistake. The hosts file was renamed by textEdit to hosts.rtf without my knowledge. Once that was fixed everything was back to normal.

Comment: I'd suggest if you need to change your hosts file with any kind of regularity that you use [GasMask](https://github.com/2ndalpha/gasmask) [freeware] which can edit, maintain multiple copies & switch between them on the fly.